# multiple activities are starting when on click

Tags: android, android-intent

I am calling one activity via intent when user clicks login button.When internet connection is poor user clicks the login button and activity is not started immediately so the user clicking the login button again. after some time two activities are opening.how can i resolve this.
it is fine when internet connection is good.

thanks in advance

Comment: Look for launcher mode activity. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: You can also check if there is a internet connectivity before actually navigating to next activity.

Comment: it is better to put android:launchMode="singleTop" instead of checking internet connection right

Comment: copy & paste the code here

Comment: no need problem is solved with launch mode as singleTop

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTop" is not a good solution for this use-case. I have posted the correct approach you should be following.

Comment: could you please tell me why android:launchMode="singleTop" is not good    ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is solved with `android:launchmode="singleTop"` in manifest

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check internet connection and give proper message to user when internet is not available.

You can create below method in your class to do this -

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // test for connection
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If it returns true then start new activity otherwise show inernet not available message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should not happen.

You need to first check if there is a internet connection available (**either via Mobile Internet and Wifi**)

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

This method will check if there is an internet connection available either via Mobile Internet or Wifi. You can obviously tweak this to check if an **high speed connection** is available. But for a simple login, this is enough.

Now start an `Activiy` only when this method returns `true` otherwise don't.

Please ensure that you have this permission in the Manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Glad it helped you. But the best way to say "thank you" in StackOverflow is to upvote and accept an answer. I wrote a detailed answer just to help you solve the problem in the best possible way.